# What Design Pattern to use when writing a PHP function which processes the output from another function?

Tags: javascript, php, design-patterns, architecture

I have two functions: `myFunctionA()` and `myFunctionB()`.

`myFunctionA()` returns an `Object` which includes the key `Page_Type` which has a string value.

`myFunctionB()` processes a number of entries in the `Object` returned by `myFunctionA()`, including `Page_Type` and its string value.

Later, `myFunctionA()` is updated so it no longer returns an object including the key `Page_Type` but, instead, the key `Page_Types` - which has an array value.

Because of this, `myFunctionB()` will now **also need to be updated** - it will no longer be processing `Page_Type` which is a string, but `Page_Types` which is an array.

If I understand correctly (and I may not), the above is an example of *Dependency Request* and the extensive refactoring that it throws up can be avoided by (I think) deploying the *Dependency Injection* pattern (or possibly even the *Service Locator* pattern?) instead (??)

But, despite reading around this subject, I am still uncertain as to how Dependency Injection can work in PHP or Javascript functions (much of the explanation deals with programming languages like `C++` and OOP concepts like `Classes`, whereas I am dealing with third party functions in PHP and javascript).

Is there *any way* to structure my code so that updating `myFunctionA()` (in any significant manner) will not then require me to also update `myFunctionB()` (and *all other* functions calling `myFunctionA()` - for instance `myFunctionC()`, `myFunctionD()`, `myFunctionE()` etc.) ?

And what if `myFunctionH()` requires `myFunctionG()` requires `myFunctionF()` which requires `myFunctionA()`? I don't want to be in a position where updating `myFunctionA()` now means that three more functions (`F`, `G` and `H`) all have to be updated.

---

## Attempt at an answer:

The best answer I can think of at present - and this may not be a *best practice* answer because I don't know yet if there is a formal problem which corresponds with the problem I am describing in the question above - is the following restatement of how I presented the setup:

> I have two (immutable) functions: `myFunctionA__v1_0()` and `myFunctionB__v1_0()`.
>
> `myFunctionA__v1_0()` returns an Object which includes the key
>   `Page_Type` which has a string value.
>
> `myFunctionB__v1_0()` processes a number of entries in the Object
>   returned by `myFunctionA__v1_0()`, including `Page_Type` and its
>   string value.
>
> Later, `myFunctionA__v1_0()` still exists but is also succeeded by `myFunctionA__v2_0()` which
>   returns an object including the key `Page_Types` - which has an array value.
>
> In order for `myFunctionB` to access the object returned by `myFunctionA__v2_0()`,
>   there will now also need to be a `myFunctionB__v1_1()`, capable of processing
>   the array `Page_Types`.

This can be summarised as:

- `myFunctionB__v1_0()` requires object returned by `myFunctionA__v1_0()`
- `myFunctionB__v1_1()` requires object returned by `myFunctionA__v2_0()`

Since each function becomes *immutable* after being formally named, what *never happens* is that we end up with an example of `myFunctionB__v1_0()` requiring object returned by `myFunctionA__v2_0()`.

I don't know if I am approaching this the right way, but this is the best approach I have come up with so far.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "dependency injection" (which is a practice) with "dependency injection container" (which is a concrete solution/library and has an alternative in "service locator" solution). Also, start pushing for use of OOP instead of this procedural madness.

Comment: Thanks, @tereško. In order to ensure that a given function does not invoke a function which then returns data that the first function cannot process, can you recommend an explicit alternative approach to versioning functions by name and then making them immutable (as I have suggested above)?

Comment: What you have there is a "published API", but because of the stupid insistence on using functions, you are not able to use interfaces for boundaries (input and output). So, either start using classes like it's 21st century or stick with versioned and immutable functions. This is a self-inflicted injury.

Comment: Thank you. I should underline (although it should be apparent) that I am not a programmer. Do you have any reading pointers with regard to "input / output interfaces & boundaries"? I found this on OOP: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSummer2012/cs312/lectures/oop.html but it's fairly high level / abstract. Can you recommend any others? Many thanks, @tereško.

Comment: Also I found a wikipedia entry on the [_Entity-Control-Boundary pattern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary). Is that more the kind of thing you were referring to when you mentioned "_interfaces for boundaries_" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common in programming for the *provider* - ie. `myFunctionA()` to know nothing about its *consumer(s)* `myFunctionB()`. The **only** correct way to handle this is to define an API up front and **never** change it ;)

I don't see the purpose of versioning the *consumer* - that reason would have to be "downstream" of `myFunctionB()` - ie. a *consumer* of `myFunctionB()`, that the author of `myFunctionB()` is not in control of... in which case `myFunctionB()` itself becomes a *provider*, and the author would have to deal with that (perhaps using the same pattern that you do)... But it's not *your* problem to deal with.

As for your *provider* `myFunctionA()`: If you cannot define an interface / API  for the data itself up front - ie. you know that the structure of the data will have to change (in a non-backwards-compatible way), but you don't know how... then you *will* need to version **something** *one way or another*.

You are miles ahead of most since you see this coming and plan for it from the beginning.

The only way to avoid having to make changes to the consumer `myFunctionB()` at some point, is to make **all** changes to the provider `myFunctionA()` in a backwards-compatible way. The change you describe is not backwards compatible because `myFunctionB()` cannot possibly know what to do with the new output from `myFunctionA()` without being modified.

The solution you propose sounds like it should work. However, there are at least a couple of downsides:

- It requires you to keep an ever-growing list of legacy functions around in case there are ever any consumers requesting their data. This will become very complicated to maintain, and likely impossible in the long run.
- Depending what changes need to be made in the future it might no longer be possible to produce the output for `myFunctionA__v1_0()` at all - in your example you add the possibility of several `page_types` in your system - in this case you can probably just rewrite `v1_0` to use the first and the legacy consumers will be happy. But if you decide to completely drop the concept of `page_types` from your system, you would have to plan for the complete removal of `v1_0` one way or another. So you need to establish a way to communicate this to the consumers.

The only correct way to handle this still is to define an API up front and **never** change it.

Since we have established that:

1. you **will** have to make backwards incompatible changes
2. you don't know anything about the consumers and you don't have the power to change them when needed

I propose that instead of defining an immutable API for your data, you define an immutable API that allows you to communicate to consumers when they **should** or **must** upgrade.

This might sound complicated, but it doesn't have to be:

#### Accept a version parameter in the **provider**:

The idea is to let the consumer explicitly tell the provider which version to return.

The provider might look like this:

```
function myFunctionA(string $version) {
    $page_types = ['TypeA', 'TypeB'];
    $page = new stdClass();
    $page->title = 'Page title';
    switch ($version) {
        case '1.0':
            $page->error = 'Version 1.0 no longer available. Please upgrade!';
            break;
        case '1.1':
            $page->page_type = $page_types[0];
            $page->warning = 'Deprecated version. Please upgrade!';
            break;
        case '2.0':
            $page->page_types = $page_types;
            break;
        default:
            $page->error = 'Unknown version: ' . $version;
            break;
    }
    return $page;
}
```

So the provider accepts a parameter which will contain the version that the consumer can understand - usually the one that was the newest when the consumer was last updated.

The provider makes a best-effort attempt to deliver the requested version

- if it is not possible there is a "contract" in place to inform the consumer (`$page->error` will exist on the return value)
- if it *is* possible, but there is a newer version available another "contract" is in place to inform the consumer of this (`$page->warning` will exist on the return value).

#### And handle a few cases in the **consumer(s)**:

The consumer needs to send the version it expects as a parameter.

```
function myFunctionB() {
    //The consumer tells the provider which version it wants:
    $page = myFunctionA('2.0');
    if ($page->error) {
        //Notify developers and throw an error
        pseudo_notify_devs($page->error);
        throw new Exception($page->error);
    } else if ($page->warning) {
        //Notify developers
        pseudo_notify_devs($page->warning);
    }
    do_stuff_with($page);
}
```

The second line of an older version of `myFunctionB()` - or a completely different consumer `myFunctionC()` might instead ask for an older version:

```
$page = myFunctionA('1.1');
```

This allows you to make backwards-compatible changes any time you want - without consumers having to do anything. You can do your best to still support old versions when at all possible, providing "graceful" degradation in legacy *consumers*.

When you do have to make *breaking changes* you can continue supporting the old version for a while before finally removing it completely.

#### Meta information

I'm not confident this would be useful... but you **could** add some meta information for consumers using an outdated version:

```
function myFunctionA(string $version) {
    # [...]
    if ($page->error || $page->warning) {
        $page->meta = [
            'current_version' => '3.0',
            'API_docs' => 'http://some-url.fake'
        ]
    }
    return $page;
}
```

This could then be used in the consumer:

```
pseudo_notify_devs(
    $page->error .
    ' - Newest version: ' . $page->meta['current_version'] .
    ' - Docs: ' . $page->meta['API_docs']
);
```

...if I were you I would be careful not to overcomplicate things though... Always [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you. I ***very much*** like the idea of each function returning version data and then enabling any function which _requires_ another function to have the implicit capability of inspecting the version data of the function it invokes and responding accordingly. This enables `myFunctionA__v1_0()`, `myFunctionA__v2_0()` and `myFunctionA__v2_1()` to **all** simply be called `myFunctionA()`. Brilliantly thought through.

Comment: Thinking about it further... it would be possible for an array to contain all the necessary versioning information: `'Recommended' => ['3.1.1', '3.1', '3.0'], 'Deprecated' => ['2.0'], 'Obsolete' => ['1.0']`.

Comment: Hmmm.... though... I'm not sure where this array (or your `string $version`) can go (?) It can't go in `myFunctionA()` because, self-evidently, each version of `myFunctionA()`will tell you that it is an up-to-date recommended version. (Only the later versions will tell you that that version of `myFunctionA()` is deprecated...)

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand your use case. In pretty much any real life application you will want your consumers to use the newest version possible... and you would never write a new consumer today using any version other than the newest... so what exactly is the purpose of informing the consumer about past versions? Either you are consuming the newest, you're consuming some version that **should** be updated as soon as possible, or you're trying to consume a version that is already gone. In the first case you're good, in both of the latter you need to update to the latest.

Comment: @Rounin ...depending on your case it might make sense to add some meta information describing the newest interface to anyone not using it. I've added a simple version of this idea to the answer.

Comment: @Rounin re-reading your comment I'm not sure you understood the basic idea. The consumer MUST explicitly declare which version **it** can understand when calling the provider. The provider then makes a best-effort attempt to return that version - but there is a "contract" in place to handle situations where it is not possible (or it is, but there is a newer version which should be implemented by the consumer when possible). I've edited again in an attempt to make this idea more explicit.

Comment: Right, I got it finally (!) I went out for a walk to think about how all the pieces fit together and as I thought it through I realised what I hadn't initially understood about your suggested approach (precisely what you re-explained immediately above) - that __the Consumer explicitly states the version of the Producer it is expecting__ and the Producer _then_ responds to that expectation. (ie. it's not the Consumer that switches to different functions to handle the data output from the Producer - it's the Producer which modifies its data output to match what the Consumer is expecting).

Comment: Your ideas and contributions have been hugely helpful - thank you very much, @Mikk3lRo. I thought I'd add a few final notes so that you can see what my approach will be moving forward. [1/4]

Comment: 1) Each Producer will optionally contain a _Versioning Manifest_. 2) Any Producer without a _Versioning Manifest_ will be treated as _v1.0_. 3) Likewise, any Consumer requesting a Producer without explicitly stating a version number will be regarded as asking for _v1.0_. 4) Whenever a _Versioning Manifest_ is present in the function, its highest numbered key will indicate the version of the function. [2/4]

Comment: 5) The subsequent (ie. earlier version) numbers will each point to a list of internal functions (inside the Producer) which transform the data output from the current version into an appropriate data output for the earlier version, just before it is returned. 6) If a Consumer requests a Producer with a version number higher than the highest key in the _Versioning Manifest_, the Consumer will be informed that it needs to try downloading that new version of the Producer. [3/4]

Comment: 7) If the Producer is so radically refactored / rebuilt that it's impractical to associate its data output with the data output from earlier versions (or find much of relationship between them), then, ***only at this point***, the Producer name can be changed from `myFunctionA()` to `myFunctionA_2021()`. [4/4]

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is more relevant in a OOP context. However, the main thing I would do here is to stop thinking in terms of returning what you have available and start considering how the 2 methods work together and what's their contract.

Figure out what's the logical output for myFunctionA(), encode that contract into an object, and convert the data you have to that format. This way, even if the way you fetch data in myFunctionA() changes, you only have to update that one conversion.

As long as you adhere to that contract (which can represented through a custom object), myFunctionB() and other methods that expect to receive data as per the contract, you won't have to change those methods any longer.

So my main take away here would be to start thinking about the data you need and pass it around not in the structure you receive it, but in the way that it makes the most sense for your application.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this is a difficult situation because what I'm dealing with here are not first party authored functions but third party authored functions (ie. user-authored-functions). We might have a team in San Francisco who have authored `myFunctionA()` and a team in Bangalore who have authored `myFunctionB()` which requests the returned output of `myFunctionA()` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have broken the interface between myFunctionA and myFunctionB by changing the return type from string to array.
I don't think DI can be of help.

Comment: Thanks. These are third-party functions (ie. user-authored-functions). We can assume that the author of `myFunctionA()` will not know that the author of `myFunctionB()` is requesting the output of the former as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is not Dependency Injection.

Your `myFunctionA()` could be call a Producer since it provide data, it should be proved a `Data Structure`.
Your `myFunctionB()` could be call a Consumer since it consume the data that provided by `myFunctionA`.

So in the order to make your Producers and your Consumer working independently, you need to add another layer between them, call `Converter`. The `Converter` layer will convert the `Data Structure` that provided by `Producer` to be a well know `Data Structure` that can understand by a `Consumer`

I really  recommend you to read the book `Clean Code` chapter 6: Objects and data structures. So you will able to fully understand the concept above, about `Data Structure`

Example

Assume we had `Data Structure` call `Hand`, had property right hand and left hand.

```
class Hand {
    private $rightHand;
    private $leftHand
    // Add Constructor, getter and setter
}
```

`myFunctionA()` will provide object `Hand`, `Hand` is a `Data Structure`

```
function myFunctionA() {
    $hand = Hand::createHand(); //Assume a function to create new Hand object
    return $hand;
}
```

let said we had another `Data Structure`, call `Leg`, the Leg will able to consume by myFunctionB();

```
class Leg {
    private $rightLeg;
    private $leftLeg
    // Add Constructor, getter and setter
}
```

Then, we need to had a converter, in the middle , to convert from Hand to Leg, and use on `myFunctionB()`

```
class Converter {
    public static function convertFromHandToLeg($hand) {
        $leg = makeFromHand($hand); //Assume a method to convert from Hand to Leg
        return $leg; 
    }
}
myFunctionB(Converter::convertFromHandToLeg($hand))
```

So, whenever you edit the response of `myFunctionA()`, mean you are going to edit `Data Structure` of `Hand`. You only need to edit the `Converter` to make sure it continue to convert from `Hand` to `Leg` correctly. You do not need to touch `myFunctionB` and vice versa.

This will very helpful when you had another `Producer` that will provide `Hand` like you mention on your question, `myFunctionC()`, `myFunctionD()`... And you also had many another `Consumer` that will consume `Leg` like `myFunctionH()`, `myFunctionG()`...

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I will read chapter 6 of _"Clean Code"_ by Robert C. "Uncle Bob" Martin. In the setup that I have, *any* Producer function will output a PHP Associative Array and *any* Consumer will consume a PHP Associative Array. (So I think I am halfway there (?) ) But I am still left with trying to understand how to deal with the scenario outlined in the question above, where a value type of the Producer's associative array is updated and no longer the type of value the Consumer expects to consume (ie. it's now an `array` instead of a `string`).

Comment: I see that on page 97, Martin is precisely describing the issue I am confronting: _"Procedural code makes it hard to add new data structures because all the functions must change."_

Comment: I read the chapter but I've not been struck by a lightning bolt of epiphany. I suspect what might make this scenario particularly unusual is asymmetric knowledge: that is, the author of the Producer will not know about the Consumer or whether the Consumer even exists. Only the author of the Consumer knows about the existence and structure of the Producer. (But for all I know, in the world of programming that might be less unusual than I suspect).

Comment: @Rounin Associative Array is a kind of Data Structure, you need a converter to go. I added example on my answer, hope this will help you. You can assume class Hand equal to an Associative Array ['leftHand' => something, 'rightHand' => something].

Comment: @Rounin Martin is precisely describing the issue I am confronting: "*Procedural code makes it hard to add new data structures because all the functions must change.*" <-- This is true, that's why we need to add a Converter layer, so we only need to edit convert function